# C++ Error when extracting subvector after reading file

Tags: c++, file, vector

I'm reading a file and creating vectors from it, and after that I'm trying to extract a subvector as follows:

```
vector<double> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
displayVector(v);
vector<double> v2(&v[1], &v[v.size()]);
displayVector(v2);
```

In this case the code works and Im just removing the first feature from the original vector, I could also do something like :

```
v.erase(v.begin());
```

which also give me the desired output, but for my application is interesting the first way.

The problem here is that Im reading from a file and building the vectors. Such file look like this:

```
1000025,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1002945,5,4,4,5,7,10,3,2,1,2
1015425,3,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2
1016277,6,8,8,1,3,4,3,7,1,2
1017023,4,1,1,3,2,1,3,1,1,2
1017122,8,10,10,8,7,10,9,7,1,4
1018099,1,1,1,1,2,10,3,1,1,2
1018561,2,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1033078,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,5,2
1033078,4,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1035283,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2
1036172,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1041801,5,3,3,3,2,3,4,4,1,4
1043999,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,1,1,2
1044572,8,7,5,10,7,9,5,5,4,4
1047630,7,4,6,4,6,1,4,3,1,4
1048672,4,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1049815,4,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1050670,10,7,7,6,4,10,4,1,2,4
1050718,6,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1054590,7,3,2,10,5,10,5,4,4,4
1054593,10,5,5,3,6,7,7,10,1,4
1056784,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
```

Where the first coordinate is not interesting for me, here is my code:

```
void displayVector (std::vector<double> &v) {
    for (auto &feature : v) {
        std::cout << feature << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void displayTrainingSet(vector<FeaturedVector> &data) {
    for (auto a : data) {
        displayVector(a);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    ifstream file;
    string filename = "breast-cancer.data";

    file.open(filename, std::ifstream::in);

    vector<FeaturedVector> data;

    while (file.good()) {
        string line;
        getline(file, line);
        istringstream buffer(line);

        double feature;
        vector<double> v;

        while (buffer >> feature) {
            if (buffer.peek() == ',') {
                buffer.ignore();
            }
            v.push_back(feature);
        }

        vector<double> v1(&v[1], &v[v.size()]);
        data.push_back(v1);
    }

    file.close();

    //displayTrainingSet(data);
    return 0;
}
```

The code above compiles, but when I try to run it gives me the weird error, which is caused by the line vector v1(&v[1], &v[v.size()]):

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::length_error: vector
Abort trap: 6
```

Does someone know why is this happening ? I know that reading from the file and creating the vector v works because I already tried to display the vector on the screen and it works fine. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you tried to single step the code?

Comment: Yup, I've tried to debug and remove and analyze line by line, but for some weird reason I get this fatal crash when trying to run the code, I does not give any compilation error because indeed the code is successfully compiled :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getline(file, line);
```

When this code reads the last line of the file, the last character in the file, the final newline, gets read. The code continues from this point, but the `file` does ***not*** have `eof` set. The `eof` bit gets set only after an attempt to read from the file fails due to the end of the file.

This hasn't happened yet. `getline()` only read as far as the last character in the file, the final newline, and stopped.

On the next iteration of the loop:

```
while (file.good()) {
```

This will succeed. As I explained, the `eof` flag is not set yet.

```
    string line;
    getline(file, line);
```

This will now fail to read anything from the file, setting the `eof` bit on the file. `line` will be an empty string.

Because `line` is now empty, the inner `while` loop will not extract anything, and

```
vector<double> v;
```

will remain an empty vector.

```
vector<double> v1(&v[1], &v[v.size()]);
```

Given that `v` is now an empty vector, `v.size()` will be 0, so what do you think is going to happen here, now?

Comment: Thank very much for this hint! I was so focused that the problem was when I was trying to create the subvector that I didn't realized this file problem, thank you very much for this, I just fixed the code making a verification before trying to extract the subvector!

Answer (score 0):

```
I modified your code a little bit to compile on my machine. i can display the data on your sample file.

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void displayVector (std::vector<double> &v) {
    for (auto &feature : v) {
        std::cout << feature << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void displayTrainingSet(std::vector< std::vector<double> > &data) {
    for (auto a : data) {
        displayVector(a);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    ifstream file;
    string filename = "C:/temp/2.txt";

    file.open(filename, std::ifstream::in);

    vector< vector<double> > data;

    while (file.good()) {
        string line;
        getline(file, line);
        istringstream buffer(line);

        double feature;
        vector<double> v;

        while (buffer >> feature) {
            if (buffer.peek() == ',') {
                buffer.ignore();
            }
            v.push_back(feature);
        }

        vector<double> v1(&v[1], &v[v.size()]);
        data.push_back(v1);
    }

    file.close();

    displayTrainingSet(data);
    return 0;
}
```